# using normal html files instead of Django templates

Tags: django

I have a bunch of html files. I'd like to render them in my Django View without converting them to Django templates. Is this possible?

Or is there any code to do the conversion easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to write a view for such cases. You can use `direct_to_template` shortcut in `urls.py` as is.

From [generic views doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views/#using-generic-views)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template


    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        ('^about/$', direct_to_template, {
            'template': 'about.html'
        }), 
   )
```

Comment: but I'm getting TemplateDoesNotExist which doesn't make sense because the html file is there...

Comment: @Kiarash, is it present in template directories?

Comment: well, I put all my html files in a folder and all the css, js files in subfolders under it. I put the main folder in the templates and now the html file loads but not the css files...

Comment: actually I understand what the problem is except I don't know how to solve it. the index.html files looks for the css files at /css/*.css but that django doesn't take /css to where it should take.

Comment: Put .html files in templates directory so that they are taken as templates (event though plain html). Other files .css, .js are considered as static files, and should be put in another folder. You need to read about serving static files in django.

Comment: yup. I see that. but then do I need to modify the html files to look into the Static folder?  instead of  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">  something like  <link href="Static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just use the following method call:

```
def main_page(request):
    template=get_template('index.html')
    variables=Context({})
    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Here your `index.html` file is located in templates folder.

Answer (score 0):

Django templates are built on top of plain old files. If you have HTML files that don't have {{ or {% in them, then they are automatically valid Templates, albeit consisting of a single Text node.

Just reference them as you would reference any template, and it will "just work".

```
return render(request, "my-plain-html-file.html")
```